# What is the difference between MonotonicRead and ReadYourWrites in RavenDB?

Tags: indexing, ravendb, isolation-level, consistency, eventual-consistency

The default ctor for DocumentConvention in RavenDB (build 888) sets the DefaultQueryingConsistency to MonotonicRead. As I understand it, this means that by default, we'll be waiting for indexes to be updated following a write. Don't get me wrong - that's great news for simplicity (especially in integration tests) but it goes against what I understood to be part of RavenDB's mantra of eventual consistency.

I've read [the article](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html) referenced in ConsistencyOptions.cs but I'm confused as to what the difference is between MonotonicRead and ReadYourWrites - they appear to be the same to me.

So: what is the difference between these two consistency models, and how does that relate to RavenDB's consistency model?

Comment: You might want to ask this question to the Raven's developers on their google groups page.  They'd know best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReadYourWrites is equivalent to doing WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite on all queries.
It means that you won't get any stale results (or get a timeout exception) from any map indexes, but that you might still get stale results from map/reduce queries.